# Why creating a new variable and using it when you can use the old variable?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

Why do we need to :-

1. Create a View x.
2. Then set x = a
3. Then use a if command on x if you can directly use a.

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       // check if the current view is reused else inflate the view
       View listItemView = convertView;

       if(listItemView == null){
           listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
       }
   ```

Instead , Why can't we do this?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
```

Comment: Not recommented to change the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and second examples are valid. Only if first case you are creating an local copy of your class variable. It is useless. Why are developers doing this way? Who knows :)

About inflating. Inflate operations some expensive, cause your adapter items are simular, it is possible to inflate view only once.

Comment: Thanks, Can you elaborate on "Inflate operations some expensive"

Comment: See here https://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/, so detailed with images.

Answer (score 1):

The second option also works perfectly. I don't know why you think you can't do that.

Just make sure you return `convertView` after doing other stuffs inside there.

Comment: Can you explain a little more , like why the second code is also valid.

Comment: It is valid because it works. Can you explain a little more, like why the second code is **not** valid?

Comment: I didn't say that the second code is not valid. what I meant was the first code is a common practice I have seen many developers do. My actual question is why create a useless variable which you don't even need.

Comment: You've asked "Why can't we do this?" and I said you can do that too. There are multiple ways of doing same thing. Both ways are perfectly valid. I have no answer why developers prefer first one. I prefer the second one though.

Answer (score 1):

As the develeoper in some cases wanted to assign a value `LayoutInflater.from(...).inflate(...)`, different from the argument `convertView`, he chose not to overwrite the argument, but to introduce a new variable. It's good style not to modify method arguments.

So, in the case that `convertView` is null, `listItemView` gets a value from the `LayoutInflater` call, to be used further down the method. And the fact that the method was called with a `null` argument is still visible.

As a more concise alternative, this can be done using Java's ternary operator:

```
View listItemView = convertView != null ?
        convertView :
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

This way the variable can even be declared `final`.